# Is it possible to test android app on Android VM under Virtual Box from Android studio running on host

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox

Did anybody try to test android apps on an Android VM
I've installed Android VM (9) under VirtualBox (5.2) and Android Studio (4.1) on a Host machine (Windows 10).
Followed the network setup steps described at
[Test android app on Virtual Box from Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252296/test-android-app-on-virtual-box-from-android-studio)
5 years ago, and can even connect to the VM from adb (running on the host) in command line, but the studio still cannot see the device.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it
It turned out there was a file named .android in the Windows user home folder.
Apparently Gradle requires .android folder there and couldn't create it. There were complaints in the Studio log that I shrugged off because they were on INFO log level:) . After I created a .android folder (renamed that .android file and not sure yet what the consequences would be) and synced Gradle the device popped up in the dropdown list. \o/